# If and else both statement executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looping through all entries from database and using an if condition to check if the departmentID matches to my given ID.
Problem is when the If condition is true it also runs the else condition but when the condition is false it only runs the else part which is fine.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "php/getall.php",
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(result) {
    employees = result['data'];
    console.log(employees);

    employees.forEach((employee) => {
      if (employee.departmentID === deptid) {
        $('#preventdel').modal('show');
      } else {
        $('#confirmdel').modal('show');
      }
    })
  }
})
```

It shows both modals if the condition is true but if the condition is not met it works fine

If and else both executing want to exit the loop if the condition is met at once

Comment: Well you are in a loop, so you will have multiple modals, one per employee

Comment: if and else can _never_ both execute. But since you are in a loop here, you are performing those checks _multiple_ times, so of course it can go into the if branch in some of the cases, and into the else branch for the others.

Comment: _"want to exit the loop if the condition is met at once"_ - what sense does that make? If you exit the loop in _both_ cases, then this will only ever do something for the _first_ employee in the list. But if that was really all you wanted to do, you would not need to _loop_ in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing your code inside a loop, so there should be as many modals as there are elements in the employee, because You are using if-else statement. So one of those two blocks of code will execute for each element.

```
const hasEmployee = employees.some(employee => employee.departmentID === deptid);
    
if (hasEmployee) {
  $('#preventdel').modal('show');
} else {
  $('#confirmdel').modal('show');
}
```

By using [some()](https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-some-and-find-f9fb9826ddfd) method, You can check if your searched elements exists in your results. Then open your modal only once at the end.